# error: exepected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'tWordInfo' in C

Tags: c

I've got this 3 files in C, one is a header file, the other one is dictionary.c and the last one is the main.c

dictionary.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"


/* Calculate the edition distance between two strings */
int getDistance(char* ref,char* word) {
char* w1=NULL;
char* w2=NULL;
int dist=0;
int i=0;
bool different=false;

/* Put the shortest word on w1 and the longest on w2. */
if(strlen(ref)<=strlen(word)) {
    w1=ref;
    w2=word;
} else {
    w1=word;
    w2=ref;
}

/* Copare char to char */
for(i=0;i<strlen(w2);i++) {

    if(different) {
        /* If the words are different, increase the distance */
        dist++;
    } else {
        /* Compare the new char and word lenghts */
        if(i<strlen(w1)) {
            different=w1[i]!=w2[i];
        } else {
            /* w1 is shorter than w2 */
            different=true;
        }
        if(different) {
            /* If the words are different, increase the distance */
            dist++;
        }
    }
}

return dist;
}

/* Get word information */
bool getWordInfo(char* str,char* word,int* languageID,int* wordID){
    *languageID=-1;
    *wordID=-1;
    sscanf(str,"%s ; %d ; %d",word,languageID,wordID);
    return *languageID>0 && *wordID>0;
}

WordList create(){
    WordList l;
    l.act = 1;
    l.nelem = 0;
    return l;
};

WordList insert(WordList l, tWordInfo e){
    int i;
    if (l.nelem == [250]){
        printf("error");
    }else{
        for (i=l.nelem; l.act; i--){
            l.WordInfo[i+1]= l.WordInfo[i];
        }
        l.WordInfo[l.act]= e;
        l.nelem = l.nelem + 1;
        l.act = l.act + 1;
    }
    return l;
}
```

dictionary.h

```
/* Declare the boolean type */
typedef enum {false, true} bool;



/* Calculate the edition distance between two strings */
int getDistance(char* ref,char* word);

/* Get word information */
bool getWordInfo(char* str,char* word,int* languageID,int* wordID);

char tWordInfo(int* languageID, int* wordID, char* word[128]);

typedef struct {
    char tWordInfo[250];
    int act;
    int nelem;
}tWordList, WordList;

WordList create(); 

WordList insert(WordList l, tWordInfo e);
```

and the last one main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char word1[128];
    char word2[128];
    int langId1,wordId1;
    int langId2,wordId2;
    int d1,d2; 
    WordList l;
    tWordInfo e;

    create();
    printf("%d\n", l.act);
    printf("%s\n", l.tWordInfo[l.act]);
    printf("%d\n", l.nelem);

    getWordInfo("hospital ; 1 ; 1",word1,&langId1,&wordId1);
    getWordInfo("hola ; 1 ; 2",word2,&langId2,&wordId2);

    d1=getDistance(word1,word2);
    d2=getDistance(word2,word1);

    printf("[%d,%d] => %s\n",langId1,wordId1,word1);
    printf("[%d,%d] => %s\n",langId2,wordId2,word2);

    printf("d(%s,%s)=%d\n",word1,word2,d1);
    printf("d(%s,%s)=%d\n",word2,word1,d2);

    return 0;
}
```

The program is not ended but I can't define the function insert, in dictionary files (.c and .h) gives me this error error: exepected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'tWordInfo' so what is the problem here and how do i fix this?

Another question is that printf of l.act and l.nelem don't give me the 1 and 0 values, gives -2 for l.act and a large number for l.nelem. Why?

Thanks

Comment: You've declared `tWordInfo`as a function in the header but are using it as a type in the main file. That is just wrong.

Comment: As well as a struct member. I don't know for sure if it's in a separate namespace, but you might want to make it different just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers I fix the problem. I was looking for a hard answer and i didn't realise how simple it could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWordInfo is declared as a function, then used as a parameter type in the insert function.  You'll need a different type for that param.